# How to find missing rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two identical tables A and B. And both the tables have same fields, as an example Table A (bin, storage, plant) and B (bin, storage, plant). But when I checked the data, table A has 5238 rows and B has 5249 rows. So I dont know which 11 rows are missing. I need help to write a query where I can find those missing rows.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: what is your primary key ?

Comment: My primary key is the Bin.But I still couldnt figure it out on which field I am missing those 11 rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can use the `EXCEPT` command for your problem:

```
SELECT bin 
  FROM tableB
EXCEPT
SELECT bin 
  FROM tableA;
```

Shows all bins which are in tableB but not in tableA.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It did worked and I found out where those missing rows. Thanks again.

Comment: So now how can I find out the exact values that are not present in the Table A or that didn't got transformed to Table A from B ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from tableA
full outer join tableB on tableA.bin = tableB.bin
where tableA.bin is null or tableB.bin is null
```

SQL-Server allows a `full outer join`. You can select all records from both table and limit the result to those where the join does not find matches on the other table.