# How to identify missing rows in a R df - without NA

Tags: r, sorting

I have several df with different length of the observations. The observations should have been collected at every 0.2 m depth. This is often the case but sometimes 1, 2 or more depth intervals are "missed out/jumped over", in a completely random order. The tables have same fields. I need to know which depth that has been missed out and at which time. As an example is a reduced file; Table A  (profile, time_UTC, depth_m). Table A has 12 rows, but should have 15 and i.e 1 at 0.4m, and at 1.2m and 1.4m. The time stamps (ms) are irregular so I cannot use them to identify gaps in depth.

==============

1. Table A
2. Has 12 rows but should have 15:

   ```
    profil time_UTC depth_m
   1 V      24871     0.2
   2 V      24877     0.6
   3 V      24882     0.8
   4 V      24887      1
   5 V      24898     1.6
   6 V      24901     1.8
   7 V      24902      2
   8 V      24905     2.2
   9 V      24907     2.4
   10 V     24909     2.6
   11 V     24912     2.8
   12 V     24915      3
   ```

The check needs to be done in an operational manner for all df that I will read in.

I need help to write a query where I can find those missing rows and add new rows with the missing depth and integrated time.

I provided two links for the similar problem, but in the R example the sequence is categorical (my df are not) and the other is for Sql code. 
[R identify missing rows from pre-specified sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34127483/8047735)
[How to find missing rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23549184/8047735)

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

right_join(df, data_frame(depth_m = seq(0.2, 3, by = 0.2)))
#> Joining, by = "depth_m"
#>    profil time_UTC depth_m
#> 1       V    24871     0.2
#> 2    <NA>       NA     0.4
#> 3    <NA>       NA     0.6
#> 4       V    24882     0.8
#> 5       V    24887     1.0
#> 6    <NA>       NA     1.2
#> 7    <NA>       NA     1.4
#> 8       V    24898     1.6
#> 9       V    24901     1.8
#> 10      V    24902     2.0
#> 11      V    24905     2.2
#> 12   <NA>       NA     2.4
#> 13   <NA>       NA     2.6
#> 14   <NA>       NA     2.8
#> 15      V    24915     3.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! The dplyr line is almost doing the trick.  But, it is introducing 4 NA rows where I have data, as for 0.6 and 2.4:2.8 mm, that I need to keep. Why is it so? The df I am working with has 27 more columns with information that is necessary to keep, like e.g the time_UTC and other parameters.

Comment: The reason is because the inexact matching of doubles. 0.6 in df is not == to 0.6 in the other dataframe for some reason. (you can see this yourself by running `sprintf("%.54f",df$depth_m[2])`. I'm not sure how to get around it other than coercing the depth_m column to a string, joining, and the coercing it back into a double.

Comment: Yes, indeed. When changing it to as.character it works. Thank you for the help! /Therese